# How post-increment & pre-increment both are evaluated in function argument?

Tags: c, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [post and pre increment in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902638/post-and-pre-increment-in-c)
>   [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

here i want to know why this output comes??
Any one Can Explain me All in proper manner

```
#include<stdio.h>
   int main() {
   int a=5;
   printf("%d %d %d",a++,a++,++a);
   return 0;
   }
```

the output of this program is like

In LINUX
 7 6 8

Comment: Jeez, not again...

Comment: Undefined behavior...soon to be closed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606655/pre-fix-and-post-fix-increment-in-c/7606673#7606673

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points actually answers your question.

Comment: @Sam_k: means that your code exhibits "undefined behavior" (=as far as the standard is concerned anything can happen), and that this question will be soon closed because there are a million other questions on this same exact topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's undefined - side effects are only guarantied to be completed at [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Answer (score 1):

We can't. This is completely compiler dependent in what order the arguments are evaluated.

Comment: Actually behavior is undefined here - `,` in the parameters list is not a sequence point.