# Multle ++ statements in single cout

Tags: c++, cout

Can someone explain why the following two snippets have different output?

```
int x=0;
cout<<x++<<" "<<x++;
```

and

```
int x=0;
cout<<x++<<" ";
cout<<x++;
```

Comment: It is undefined behavior. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874399/how-post-increment-pre-increment-both-are-evaluated-in-function-argument

Answer (score 1):

The former is undefined behaviour, since it involves two unsequenced writes to `x`. Undefined behaviour means anything goes.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple writes on the same object between two sequence points is undefined behavior.  Your first code snippet modifies the value of `x` twice before the next sequence point appears, so it's undefined behavior.  Don't write code like this.  Exploring the possible outputs of this code on different implementations is also meaningless.

Answer (score -2):

```
int x = 0; cout<<x++<<" "<<x++
```

is similar to,

```
int x = 0;
cout<<x;
cout<<" ";
x = x+1;
x = x+1;
```

So at that line you will get printed a **0**, while `x` will be **2** if you run a `cout<<x` just below that line.

The second statement,

```
int x=0; cout<<x++<<" "; cout<<x++;
```

is equivalent to,

```
int x =0;
cout<<x;
cout<<" ";
x = x+1; //note x gets 1 here
cout<<x; //will print 1 here due previous increment, not the second one
x = x +1;
```

So in this case you will get printed a **1**, but again `x` will be **2** if you run a `cout<<x` at the next line.

Comment: it's undefined behaviour, see other answers